# Is 'Some I understood, some not.' an OK spoken response?

Tags: phrase-usage, spoken-english

> 'How much did you understand the content of the new play?'
>   'Some I understood, some not.'

In the short dialog above, Is this reply acceptable in talk?

Comment: That kind of response would be common enough in normal speech, although there are some grammatical tweaks that would make it better English.  For example, "...some I didn't" would be better than "...some not".  Is there a specific aspect you're questioning?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this reply is suitable. However, for natives, the conversation would generally go more like this:

> Did you understand the new play?
>
> Some of it.

Comment: Perhaps "How well did you understand..." "Not so well..."